# Number rows limit in report export

Tags: reporting, limits

I would like to know which is the row number limit when you make an export of a report (usingExport details or Printable view).

I'm going to export a tabular report with 50.000 rows.

Thanks,BR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some reporting limits described [here](https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/faq_reports_common_limits.htm), stating a limit on screen of 2,000, the following is stated when exporting...

> To view all the rows, export the report to Excel or use the printable view for tabular and summary reports. For joined reports, export is not available, and the printable view displays a maximum of 20,000 rows.

For an even more extensive list of **Analytics Limits** see [here](http://na13.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/limits_analytics_all_editions.htm). I cannot see either of the above being explicit about an export limit however. So my guess is the next limit will likely not be rows, but timeout...

> By default, reports time out after 10 minutes. Contact salesforce.com to extend the time-out limit to 20 minutes for tabular, summary, and matrix reports (joined reports will continue to time out after 10 minutes).

This document on [Maximising Report Performance](http://na13.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_reportperformance_cheatsheet.pdf) is a good resource if you hit this limit.

> If your reports still take more
>   than 10 minutes to complete after trying all the tips given here, contact Salesforce support.

There is also a Background Export feature described [here](https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/reports_background.htm).

> Exporting reports to the background allows you to successfully run data-intensive reports, which would otherwise time out due to the large number of report results.